# Call a command in a command function

Tags: c++, c, command-line

There're two commands:

```
static int Abc_CommandTest      ( Abc_Frame_t * pAbc, int argc, char ** argv );
static int Abc_CommandPrintExdc ( Abc_Frame_t * pAbc, int argc, char ** argv );
```

How to call `Abc_CommandPrintExdc` inside `Abc_CommandTest`?

```
int Abc_CommandTest      ( Abc_Frame_t * pAbc, int argc, char ** argv )
{
    Abc_CommandPrintExdc(...); // arg?
}
```

**EDIT**:

Users use "`Abc_CommandPrintExdc [argument]`" in terminal.

Users use "`Abc_CommandTest`" in terminal.

`Abc_CommandTest` will determine [argument] used in `Abc_CommandPrintExdc`.

The two `argv` are different?

Comment: Please pick up a [_good book_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that covers C++.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like both of those commands take the same parameters; is there a reason you can't just pass them straight through?

```
Abc_CommandPrintExdc(pApb, argc, argv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a trick question?  What's wrong with:

```
static int Abc_CommandTest(Abc_Frame_t *pAbc, int argc, char **argv)
{
    return Abc_CommandPrintExdc(pAbc, argc, argv);
}
```